# What is wrong with this `zip` command for creating a multi-segment archive?

Tags: zip, archive

Looking at [this](https://askubuntu.com/q/54654/47206) question, I was curious whether a `zip` command could be used in a file-manager context menu to create multiple 20MB zip files (the level accepted by a gmail message). The answers to that question show that `rar` and `7z` multi-files can be easily created, but I wondered if `zip` files can be as accessible.

A command like the one presented [here](https://www.lifewire.com/practical-examples-of-the-zip-command-2201158) should work. Both in a terminal and in Thunar custom actions I have seen the same result with this command:

```
zip my_archive.zip -r /path/to -s 20m
```

the version for Thunar is

```
zip my_archive.zip -r %f -s 20m
```

But the resulting archive (*my_archive.z01, my_archive.z02, my_archive.z03..., my_archive.zip*) cannot be opened.

Maybe that is expected, as I see [here](https://serverfault.com/a/760341/256174) that those resulting files have to be "unsplit" before being "unzipped", with the command

```
 zip -s 0 my_archive.zip --out unsplit.zip
```

(I have to say I didn't expected the need for that, as usually other multi-file archives do not need to be re-joined before being extracted, and even an archive split with `hjsplit` gives multiple archive-volumes that can be directly extracted. But that's another matter.)

Only that the `unsplit.zip` file also gives an error upon extraction.

```
$ unzip unsplit.zip
Archive:  unsplit.zip
  inflating: home/cip/Desktop/R/Interviu/20170918.3gpp  
  error:  invalid compressed data to inflate
```

The archive cannot be extracted, but it can be opened (explored inside an archive manager) and it has an odd folder-inside-folder structure (reflecting the path where it was created initially; as in the `inflating` line above).

What is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a [known issue](http://www.info-zip.org/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=383) in `zip`: it fails to recombine archives split on multiples of the internal buffer size (16KiB). For now you need to split on a different size... In your case, 20971519 (20MiB minus one byte) should work fine.

(I tried manually recombining a split archive, but `zip -FF` looks for the archive components and fails to fix the combined file.)

It turns out that [File Roller](http://fileroller.sourceforge.net/) supports split archives (without following the segmented archive format), so if your recipients all use that (or presumably, other archivers using [libarchive](http://libarchive.org/)), you can split your archive using `split` or a similar tool. For this to work, you need to generate files using `split`’s default suffixes, `aa`, `ab` etc:

```
split -b20m archive.zip split.z
```

Then File Roller will let you open `split.zaa`, and extract the whole archive transparently (as long as all the pieces are present obviously).

Comment: So, the multi-file archive is not ready to be extracted (needs a supplementary `zip -s 0` command to create a 1-file archive) and this limitation cannot be avoided. Sending a such multi-archive to somebody that doesn't know this is pointless in this case.

Comment: Yes, `7z` is a better solution for now (which is a shame really given how well multi-archive ZIP support works on other platforms).

Comment: I have found a multi-command for zip files that be added to the file-manager context menu and get with just one click a multi-volume archive ready to be extracted: `zip -j my_archive.zip %F && split -b 20m my_archive.zip split.zip && rm my_archive.zip`; more as an answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/957339/47206).

Comment: That still leaves the same reconstruction problem though... If your archives contents are all files smaller than 20MB individually, you could look at `zipsplit` instead; that will produce split archives which are individually valid and thus easier to extract.

Comment: the split is done with `split`, not with `zip`, and doesn't seem affected by the 20MB problem; the command above works, I have tested it

Comment: I know it’s not affected, but you still need to explain to your recipient how to reconstruct the archive.

Comment: the multi-archive created by `split` (as a splitting of the initial one-file archive) can be directly extracted, unlike the one created with `zip`

Comment: Wow now I’m curious. Don’t you need to `cat split.zip* > archive.zip` first?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/65829/discussion-between-cipricus-and-stephen-kitt).

Comment: For possibly being useful to others: as you said in chat, `file-roller` is needed to extract the archives created with the above command. I can confirm that they also can be extracted in Windows with 7-zip, but not with winrar.